# How to pass downloaded image from Parent to Child route without new server request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, rxjs, firebase-storage

I am using firebase and Angular+Ionic to  build a blog app. When I load the list of blogs, I send a request to firebase to get the image download url for each blog thumbnail then set the img src attribute to the returned URL. I have done this with a pipe like so:

```
<!-- refToPic converts the blog photo reference into a download url-->

<ion-img style="height:250px; object-fit:cover" src="{{blog.headerPhoto | refToPic | async}}"></ion-img>
```

When the user then clicks on a blog item to open the blog, I don't want to send another request to fetch the image to render the blog header as it is the same as the image in the thumbnail. Is there a way (elegant or not) to cache the image and then pass it to the blog detail page without redoing the server request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your thumbnail and actual Image are same i.e. you are not saving them differently, then the URL will be same in Both the pages.You won't need any additional cache in this case because browser already does that to improve performance.

Additionally, you can use [ionic-img-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-cache) to achieve this if the underlying WebView does not cache the images. You would require 3 additional plugins with it:

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```